# Compressing KML files

Tags: compression, openlayers, kml

is there anyway to compress a KML file?

My KML files are created once pr. night. And are allways named the same. But the biggest file takes up almost 10mb. And that takes about 10 seconds to download on a computer with high speed internet. I would like for this file to either be smaller. or if there are some other ways to minimize the file content, without loosing any features i would like to know :)

Im using Openlayers to view the map and load the KML files.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first thing to try is gzip compression - check out this - https://developers.google.com/speed/articles/gzip

Comment: Thank you, im trying to look into this. Do you have any tips on how to achive this?

Comment: Sure, first you can go to http://www.gzip.org/ and try gzip-ing your KML files to see how much space you will save. Then you should google "how to enable gzip on XYZ" where XYZ is your webserver type (ex. Apache, IIS etc). After it is enabled, the rest should be transparent to you and any users of your app.

Answer (score 1):

KMZ files are zipped KML files.

[KMZ Files](https://developers.google.com/kml/documentation/kmzarchives)

Comment: Yes, but Openlayers does not support KMZ files. and JS cannot unzip it either. Its not for saving space on webserver. its for saving loading time to browser.

Comment: FWIW - [geoxml3](http://code.google.com/p/geoxml3/) can unzip KMZ files (the codebase in the kmz branch).  I don't know that browser based zip compression is the most efficient way to do it though...